# print product attributes with their values

Tags: php, mysql

How do I print the attributes and values together by placing each value under the attribute it belongs. So one attribute and several values under.

```
//i can have the array the normal way if it helps, like [0] => Red...
[attribute] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Colour] => Red
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Colour] => Blue
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Colour] => Green
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Size] => Small
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Size] => Medium
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Size] => Large
            )

    )
```

If this can be done in the query by returning one attribute instead of multiple attributes and the values that go with it, that's great. But I'd also like to see this done by printing the array key once and then the values, I will +1 it.

```
SELECT `attribute`, `value` 
FROM (`attribute_value`) 
JOIN `product_attr_value` ON `product_attr_value`.`attribute_value_id` = `attribute_value`.`id`  
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_attr_value`.`product_id` 
WHERE `products`.`item_name` LIKE '%qwe2%'
```

EDIT:

file1

```
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

return $set;
```

file2

```
foreach ($attr_value as $val)
{
echo $val['attribute'] ."<br>";

$values = $val['group_concat(`value`)'];
$value = explode(",", $values);
echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `group by`:

```
SELECT attribute, group_concat(`value`)
FROM attribute_value av JOIN
     product_attr_value pav
     ON pav.attribute_value_id = av.id JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = pav.product_id
WHERE p.`item_name` LIKE '%qwe2%'
group by attribute;
```

I also added table aliases to avoid repeating the long table names throughout the query.

`group_concat()` will concatenate the values into a single string.  By default, these are separated by a comma.  You can control that with the `SEPARATOR` keyword.

Comment: OK, I tried to figure this out but firstly, I am getting duplicates. I tried group by pav.attribute_value_id because that's how I got my first result, but that's not working. Secondly I can't seem to print the values. Please take a look at the EDIT.

Comment: @ethio . . . Did you try this query?  I suspect that `pav.attribute_value_id ` is a unique id on each row in that table.  Aggregating by it will not do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I used it to stop the values for different attributes mixing with each other and to stop duplicates. pav.attribute_value_id is primary key in attribute_value for a specific attribute and value.

Comment: I'm using 'distinct' so I'm not getting duplicates now.